# How can I configure my Android device to use Internet via Bluetooth tethering as a metered connection?

Tags: android-13, bluetooth-tethering, samsung-one-ui, samsung-galaxy-s-23, metered-connection

I use Internet on my S23 Ultra phone via Bluetooth tethering. How can I configure my Android device to use Internet via Bluetooth tethering as a metered connection?